# HTML: Input type=file, but file system is of server

Tags: html

There is a requirement in which we need to show the file system of the server, to choose a file from just like currently tag  shows the file system of client machine where browser is running.

Is there something like this available?

Answer (score 4):

Not built in to HTML, no.

You would need a server side program (in some language supported by the server) which would read the available files and present a listing (with some associated radio buttons or checkboxes) to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it yourself. HTML does not support stuff like that natively.

There are lots of libraries outthere, that makes it look like it actually is a HTML thing, but it indeed under the hood is using some sort of a serverside language.

Comment: hi, can you suggest some of the libraries which i can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Apache can show you a list of files. Maybe that is what you need:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: hi, i actually need a file chooser which selects file from server file system.